# What’s the short story about a grandfather and a child living in a world where they have to watch adverts all the time?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, soft-sci-fi

I can’t remember the author and title. The basic premise is that the two of them are living in a world where adverts are streaming directly into their vision, for example when they see an object, a relevant advertisement will surface in their vision. They can’t turn it off as the device will sense it, and I think they will incur a penalty if they do so.

There might be something about buying shoes for the boy, but I’m not too sure about that detail.